# Puppeteer abort file download to disk - how to implement it?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Good day to everyone. I have a very simple code that downloads a file to a hard drive. It works flawlessly. Goes to the site, clicks on the link to which the file is linked, then the baruser saves this file to the default path. **But there are times when I need to cancel the file upload after it has already started. How do I do this?**

*Example*

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
async function main() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--window-size=1200,1400',
            '--window-position=000,000',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
            '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
        ]
    })
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://example.com/');
    await page.waitForSelector('#download');
    await page.hover('#download');
    await page.click('#download'); // After clicking on the link, the file download begins
}

main().catch((e) => {
    throw e
})
```

```html
<a href="/files.zip" id="download">download files</a>
```

- nodejs v12.22.9
- Chromium Version 101.0.4950.0 (Developer Build)
  (64-bit)
- puppeteer ^13.7.0
- puppeteer-extra ^3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clicking on the link, you could get file path and fetch file with stream.

```
const https = require('https');

let stream
function abortStream() {
  if (stream) {
    stream.abort();
  }
}

// ... your code


const filePath = await page.$eval('#download', file => file.href);
const url = 'https://somesite.com'
https.get(`${url}${filePath}`, res => {
  stream = fs.createWriteStream('file.zip');
  res.pipe(stream);
  stream.on('error', ()=>{
     stream = undefined;
  })
  stream.on('finish', () => {
     stream.close();
     stream = undefined;
  })
})
```

Call `abortStream()` to abort a file download.